# Reading a text file linewise

Tags: io, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
0.031 0.031 0.031 1.4998 0.9976 0.5668 0.9659
0.062 0.031 0.031 0.9620 0.7479 0.3674 0.4806 
0.094 0.031 0.031 0.3549 0.0738 0.0054 0.3471
0.125 0.031 0.031 0.4270 0.3422 0.2180 0.1332
0.156 0.031 0.031 1.0766 0.9005 0.3868 0.4455
0.188 0.031 0.031 0.9285 0.6619 0.0161 0.6509
0.219 0.031 0.031 1.1200 0.6464 0.3230 0.8557
```

and so on...(32768 lines because it's a 32^3 grid.)
The first three columns represent x,y and z coordinates , the 4th column being the norm of the coordinates and  the last three columns represent the components of a 3D vector. I need to calculate curl and divergence of the vector field( 5,6,7) using central difference method at each point. Since there are a lot of lines, I want to parallelize the input using MPI. But for this to happen,I need to have access to three lines at once as central difference method states (for eg) 
My fortran code for reading in data from the file is:

```
  open(unit = 1,file = '32data.txt') ! 
  do i = 1,32767
  read(1,*) x(i),y(i),z(i),norm(i),xv(i),yv(i),zv(i)
  end do
  do i = 2,32767
  dx = x(i) - x(i-1)
  dy = y(i) - y(i-1)
  dz = z(i) - z(i-1)
  Fx(i) = (xv(i+1) - xv(i-1))/(2.0)*dx
  Fy(i) = (yv(i+1) - yv(i-1))/(2.0)*dy
  Fz(i) = (zv(i+1) - zv(i-1))/(2.0)*dz
  div(i) = Fx(i)+Fy(i)+Fz(i)
  end do
```

So I need to send chunk of lines to different processes. BUT there's a problem here. Let's say process 2 takes 4 lines and process 3 takes the next 6. To calculate the gradient for the first line in process 3, I need data from the previous line in process 2. So I need to send that again to process 3. So is it possible to parallelize this in MPI? Or should I follow something else?

Comment: Why do you need to parallelize that? Is the rest of program distributed already?  If not, forget it. Unless you have some special hardware, it won't be faster. And MPI-IO is much better for binary files, than for text files.

Comment: Also, MPI and multithreading are two completely diiferent things. Choose one, delete the other tag.

Comment: Would you suggest me to use openmp or MPI for this? @VladimirF . Can the computation part (the calculation of curl and divergence) be parallelized? I think it can be done only in openMP and not MPI. Or can it?

Comment: It can be done in both. But first you must know OpenMP or MPI and you must know what you are doing. We cannot parallelize a code for you.

Comment: So, if you go through the trouble of parallelizing the code considering above comments, what you do is overlap a few lines of data. Example, process 1 reads in lines 1-5001 but computes through 5000. Process 2 reads in lines 5000-10001 but processes 5001-10000. etc.

Comment: keep in mind converting a floating number from text to binary requires some resources, and this is yet an other reason to have your data in binary format in the first place.

Comment: To take a contrarian view: don't bother parallelising this bit of code.  Really, these days, `32^3*7` real numbers isn't very much data, less than 1MB if my calculations are correct.  And the amount of computation borders on the trivial.  As a rule of thumb -- if it's not worth reading and writing data in binary it's not worth parallelising.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Actually this is a small datafile. I have a 512^3 data file which is pretty large. But if i have access to a supercomputer, I don't need to parallelize it right?

Comment: *I don't need to parallelize it right?*  That's not a conclusion you should draw from my previous comment.

Comment: I suggest you make some performance analysis of this kernel and check where the time is spent. reading a binary file ? reading a text file ? doing the computation ? that should give an indication of if/how parallelization can help.